# Ember - Attempting to register an unknown factory

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

I have my route structure like this:

```
abc (route)
    |-- index
    |       |-- route.js (extends base.js)
    |       |-- template.hbs
    |
    |-- edit
    |       |-- route.js (extends base.js)
    |       |-- template.hbs
    |
    |-- base.js (extends Ember.Route)
```

Now when I am trying to write the unit test for my base.js I am getting the following exception:

> Promise rejected before it exists: Attempting to register an unknown
>   factory: route:abc/base

What's wrong I have done that it isn't able to register my base class as route.?

If I change my base.js to route.js then it starts working, but what happen is that the afterModel inside base.js get executed twice when I make transition to abc/index(this is expected behavior). My base class contains code that is required by both of the index and edit route.

Is there any better way to deal with this.?

Comment: Any progress on this? If so, an update to your issue [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/issues/231) (and of course here) would probably be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have route like `abc/base` and you need that just for inheritance, move to another location.

Comment: How will I get that class for unit test.?
It isn't accessible using moduleFor

Comment: @hnf1991 move to `utils`. I'm using mixin for this situations

Comment: Yeah this is what I have tried now. It worked fine there, but when I write the unit test for that mixin it did check all the assertions but it didn't show the line coverage.?